# How can I convert a text file with numbers in it into a binary file?

Tags: c++, windows, binary, iostream, fstream

So I have made a program that opens up a text file using ifstream. Now I want to make it so it outputs this file in binary. I have tried ofstream and using .write() but when I do the program crashes. I set it up correctly when using .write() as I have seen online but I haven't seen anyone do it with what I was working with. Anybody have a solution to this? Also, I do not know why 'InputFile' and 'OutputFile' are both highlighted blue like that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Error 1";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
        ifstream InputFile;
        InputFile.open(argv[1], ios::in);
        ofstream OutputFile;
        OutputFile.open("OUTPUT.raw", ios::binary | ios::app);
        cout << "Enter Width" << endl;
        WIDTH = cin.get();
        HEIGHT = WIDTH;
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
            {
                OutputFile.write((char*)InputFile.get(), sizeof(InputFile));
            }
        }
    }
    //cout << bitset<8>(txt[i]);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: We need more info. How did you set it up? How does it crash and where?

Comment: Probably, if you show the code that fails, we can help.

Comment: Did you use the `ios::out | ios::binary` flags? Show us some code.

Comment: can you please show use the code you have tried?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to show the code here it is.

Comment: Where is it? Edit your original question to insert it.

Comment: I did. Sorry it took a minute, I'm new to this site.

Comment: Would be nice if you also show an example input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OutputFile.write((char*)InputFile.get(), sizeof(InputFile));
```

First, `istream::get()` extracts one characters from the stream and returns its value casted to an integer. The result is a temporary, which you cast to a pointer to char! It compiles, because the C-style cast basically tells the compiler "shoosh, I know what I'm doing!", but it will certainly do weird things at run-time. You need to get an adress of some object where the value you want to write is stored in, and cast that adress.

The second thing, `sizeof(InputFile)` returns size of `ifstream` class that manages the file stream. It's not in any way related to how many data is in the stream's buffer.

If you open a stream in text mode, then the correct way to extract data from it is to use extraction operator (`>>`). Then it's pretty simple:

```
std::ifstream in_file("numbers.txt");
std::ofstream out_file("numbers.bin", std::ios::binary);

int i;

while (in_file >> i)
    out_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(int));
```

The above snippet will work with an input text file like this: `-4 21 1990 5425342 -3432 0 100`.

Comment: you've been the closest so far but the problem is that my file doesn't have any spaces in the numbers. When I put a file in that had split numbers like yours it worked, but when I put my file with one big number it won't work for some reason.

Comment: And I would show you the input file, but it is to many characters to put on this site. It's pretty much just a file with a really big number.

Comment: If you want to represent that "big number" as one integer, then the problem is non-trivial. You'll need a library that can handle aribtrarily large integers.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you just want to have a version of the file with the same information but smaller size you could try to compress it instead. You can use existing compression algorithms or, if your input file has certain characteristics than can be exploited, invent something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse your text file to get `int` for every string in file and just create a new file and write your binary data with `fputc()` or `fwrite()` functions.